# Difference between su and sudo su

Tags: sudo, root, su

Asking because of curiosity. :)

When I type

```
sudo su
```

It asks for my user password. And when I type just

```
su
```

It asks for the root user password. But both the commands directs me to the root terminal. Then why is there such a difference?

Comment: @muru The OP is asking difference between `su` and `sudo su` not `sudo -s` or `sudo -s`

Comment: @NewUSer read again.

Comment: There is never a good reason to run `sudo su`. I've always wondered why this is so commonly suggested in the Ubuntu world. It is clumsy, inelegant and adds needless overhead. Just run `su` if you've set up the root account or `sudo -i` if you haven't. `sudo su` is just silly.

Comment: @terdon Usually when the user is on a corporate LAN the system administrators may not share the root user password with all the employees. In such a scenario its easier for a user to become root by putting `sudo su` and inserting user password. Since majority of Linux users are workers under corporates, say IT, I guess this could be a reason. :)

Comment: @AnonymousPlatypus no, that's when you use `sudo -i`, or `sudo -s`, you might also want to use `-E`, depending on what you want to do. What you don't want is `sudo su`. Both because there's no reason to run two programs when one is enough and because that way you can control the resulting environment much better.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`sudo su` means run the command `su` as `sudo` which means as root. Here the system will ask you for your password since you are a sudoer. After you enter your password, you now have root privileges. So `su` command won't ask for a password. It's same as if you are a root then `su` to any other user will not ask for password because you are a root.

When you just run the command `su`, you are running it as a regular user. Since `su` means switch to user root, you will be asked for the root password.

Comment: This is a good answer so I wont write another but would like to include the following detailed blog post I found http://johnkpaul.tumblr.com/post/19841381351/su-vs-sudo-su-vs-sudo-u-i